# pytest failure in a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, integration-testing, pytest

We're adapting pytest for our integration testing, and trying to use pytest fixtures to spawn some background test environment monitoring using separate threads.

The monitor threads have no problem launching at startup when we use the fixture, but I haven't found a way for pytest to fail the main test if one of the background monitor threads detects a problem.

Does anyone know a nice way to accomplish this in pytest? Is there any hook that we could use in the main pytest thread to catch a pytest.fail being called in one of our background monitor threads?

Thanks!

Comment: We found a good solution for this if anyone needs an answer. We basically  have a fixture that contains an exception_handler class that gets passed to all the fixtures doing background monitoring. There's another autouse fixture that also inherits the exception_handler and checks for errors before and after each test function.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer :-)

Comment: @KeirJackson please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: it would be great to get an example solution posted on here... I can't find anything with the search `"exception_handler" pytest`

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, this is a solution I used:

https://gist.github.com/sbrugman/59b3535ebcd5aa0e2598293cfa58b6ab

We wrap certain parts of `threading.Thread` to propagate exceptions. 
Note that this works when you have access to the location where the thread is spawned.

Comment: The link contains extremely useful info

Answer (score 3):

In case the spawning of threads can not be customized, [here](https://github.com/bjoluc/pytest-reraise)'s a little pytest plugin I wrote to capture exceptions raised in other threads and re-raise them in the main thread. It provides a `reraise` fixture that can be used as a context manager to capture exceptions:

```py
from threading import Thread

def test_assert(reraise):

    def run():
        with reraise:
            assert False

    Thread(target=run).start()
```

Comment: Please make sure to mention that you're the creator/maintainer of this package.